# How to find circumference origin position?

Tags: circles, triangles, coordinate-systems

I need to find origin of circumference which is defined by two points and vertex angle of isosceles triangle:

[image]

I've got radius of triangle by `deltaAB /2 /math.sin( math.radians( angle /2 ) )`, but what is the right equation to find circle origin?

Please disregard red circle from upper image.

Comment: What does it mean "deltaAB /2 /math.sin( math.radians( angle /2 ) )"?

Comment: Found it here: http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.07/s/cindy1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find point $T$ as $(\frac 12(x_A+x_B),\frac 12(y_A+y_B))$  Then the slope of $TO$ is the negative reciprocal of the slope of $AB$, so is $-\frac {x_B-x_A}{y_B-y_A}$.  The line TO is then $y-y_T=-\frac {x_B-x_A}{y_B-y_A}(x-x_T)$  The circle around $A$ with radius $r$ is $(x-x_A)^2+(y-y_A)^2=r^2$.  Solve these two simultaneously and you have your answer.  There are two solutions.  The other will be the other side of AB (upper left in your diagram)

Comment: Oh boy... Thanks. I didn't solved such equations since a college ... 30 years ago or so :(